# Point-N-Click doesn't click in some windows. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, dwell-clicker

I use the dwell clicker [Point-N-Click Virtual Mouse By Polital Enterprises](https://polital.com/pnc/) on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro. Point-N-Click doesn't click in some windows, e.g. VMware Workstation 16.2.3 and installation setup windows. How can I fix it?

---

Example of  installation setup windows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running Point-N-Click as an admin solves some of the issues (e.g, Point-N-Click  now clicks in installation setup windows), but some other issues remain (e.g.,  Point-N-Click still doesn't click in VMware).

[image]

[image]

For VMware, one can either use VNC:

[image]

or switch to [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), which works ok with Point-N-Click.